# Refactor function to remove unsafe .get calls when making doobie database queries

Tags: scala, scala-cats, doobie

My DAO method types are:

```
ProductDao.getById(..): ConnectionIO[Option[Product]]
InventoryDao.getById(..): ConnectionIO[Option[Inventory]]
```

The function I need to refactor to make it safe is below:

```
def getInventoryLocation(...): IO[Either[String, Int]] = {

   (for {

    product <- EitherT.fromOptionF(ProductDao.getById(id).transact(xa), "product not found")
        inventory <- EitherT.fromOptionF((InventoryDao.getById(product.inventorySectionId.get)).transact(xa), "product not found")
   } yield inventory.location.get).value
}
```

**There are 2 problems currently with the function**, it calls `.get` two times.
I need help removing those, when I try .map over the option that doesn't seem to work correctly.

```
inventory <- EitherT.fromOptionF(( product.inventorySectionId.map(InventoryDao.getById()) ).transact(xa), "product not found")
```

Because then I am returning a None and not a IO none I guess?

Answer (score 0):

Your for-comprehension already uses an `EitherT` for error handling. Assuming `product.inventorySectionId` and `inventory.location` return `Option`s, you can use `EitherT.fromOption` to make them compatible and put them into separate lines in the `for`, so you no longer have nested errors:

```
(for {
  product <- EitherT.fromOptionF(ProductDao.getById(id).transact(xa), "product not found")
  sectionId <- EitherT.fromOption(product.inventorySectionId, "section not found")
  inventory <- EitherT.fromOptionF((InventoryDao.getById(sectionId)).transact(xa), "product not found")
  location <- EitherT.fromOption(inventory.location, "location not found")
} yield location).value
```